# Custom Spring HttpMessageConverter not being used by the framework

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have a Spring mvc @RestController class where the method parameter is annotated with @RequestBody. Something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/features")
public class FeatureController {

    @PostMapping
    public Feature createFeature(@RequestBody Feature feature) {
         ......
    }
}
```

My `Feature` class has a private constructor built using a `Builder` pattern. So I created `HttpMessageConverter` called `FeatureConverter` and registered it properly using `extendMessageConverters`. The converter uses Jackson to parse the JSON and then uses `Feature.Builder` to create an instance of `Feature`.

My problem is that Spring registers an instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` before my custom `FeatureConverter`. As a result the parsing is attempted by `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` even before it can reach `FeatureConverter`. Since the constructor is private so `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` fails.

My question is how do I change the order so that `FeatureConverter` is asked before `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. Is there a proper way of doing it?

Comment: As an fyi...I can resolve this by adding the converter like this: `converters.add(0, new FeatureConverter())` which forces my converter to be tested prior to any framework converters. But is this the only way / right way?

Answer (score 4):

Spring MVC `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` initialize HttpMessageConverters like that:

```
protected final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverters() {
    if (this.messageConverters == null) {
        this.messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        configureMessageConverters(this.messageConverters);
        if (this.messageConverters.isEmpty()) {
            addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(this.messageConverters);
        }
        extendMessageConverters(this.messageConverters);
    }
    return this.messageConverters;
}
```

See: [Github - WebMvcConfigurationSupport](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java)

As you can see there is 3 method:

1. `configureMessageConverters`, empty by default it's where you are suppose to add converters
2. `addDefaultHttpMessageConverters`, where as the name said will create all default converters, the default `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is created there.
3. `extendMessageConverters` which as the documentation:

> Override this method to extend or modify the list of converters after
>   it  has been configured. This may be useful for example to allow
>   default  converters to be registered and then insert a custom
>   converter through  this method.

Is to use when you want to modify the list after having all the defaults converter added.

To answer your question, if you don't need defaults converters you just have to Override `configureMessageConverters` and add it:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new FeatureConverter());
}
```

If you need them you can either copy-paste the `addDefaultHttpMessageConverters` content and add it into `configureMessageConverters` and play with the order of initialisation there (ugly solution).

Otherwise you can use `extendMessageConverters` to add it after the default initialization and play with the order:

```
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(the_index_you_want, new FeatureConverter()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want to use your `Builder` for deserialization of `Feature` object. 
Maybe you can just use Jackson annotations (without `FeatureConverter`):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;

@JsonDeserialize(builder = Feature.FeatureBuilder.class)
public class Feature {
    private final String name;

    public Feature(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Builder
     */
    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class FeatureBuilder {
        private String name = "";

        private FeatureBuilder() {
        }

        public static FeatureBuilder create() {
            return new FeatureBuilder();
        }

        public FeatureBuilder name(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Build Feature object
         */
        public Feature build() {
            Feature feature = new Feature(this.name);
            return feature;
        }
    }
}
```

If you use `Lombok`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Feature.FeatureBuilder.class)
public class Feature {
    private final String name;

    /**
     * Builder
     */
    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class FeatureBuilder {
    }
}
```